# C# set access_type = offline for AuthorizeAsync?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am attempting to change our old rest calls for the .net client libs and I have two-ish questions/issues which are related...

The sample app on this page
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

uses AuthorizeAsync to get the user to approve the authorization, then you save the credentials somewhere....

At a later point - you want to do some offline *stuff*, for that., it has the following

> UserCredential and **AuthorizationCodeFlow take care of automatically**
>   **"refreshing" the token**, which simply means getting a new access token.
>   This is done using a long-lived refresh token, which you receive along
>   with the access token **if you use the access_type=offline parameter**
>   during the authorization code flow.

I've marked the two statement in bold that are in question.

1. How do you set this parameter using the c# client lib? AuthorizeAsync does not take in a accessType flag.
2. Do you even need to set this (AccessType)? I noticed that after approving the oauth screen - I received both the accessToken and the RefreshToken
3. Once you have the refresh token - and you need to build the credentials from the saved accesstoken and refreshtoken - do you need manually refresh the access token? or will AuthorizationCodeFlow really take care of this and do I need to remember the refreshed accessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { BooksService.Scope.Books },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
            }
```

The first thing that you should look at above is "user" this is where you denote different users.   FileDataStore stores the credentials by default in %appData% folder on your machine each user will have their own credentials file.   I have a full write up on [filedatastore](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/).

You don't need to worry about setting it to offline access or requesting a new access token when yours expires the client library will handle all of that for you.

Comment: Thanks - I'm storing it to the db - for server-side calls later - so this is where I need to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with the stored accesstoken + refreshtoken; does it work the same way? and should I be checking to see if the accesstoken is different than what I have in the db to update it?

Comment: you will need to make your own implication of Idatasrore and use that instead of filedatastore and it will work the same

Comment: I have a few examples up on github they might help https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf

Comment: Thanks - I'll go through the examples and see if it does indeed refresh the accesstoken. Someone should clean up the c# client documentation if the access_type=offline does not apply. I did run into some articles where people had their own implementation of AuthorizeAsync to push this flag...

Comment: Your going to have to wait like 55 minutes before you will see it refreshing it only does it if its needed.   Those are probably old tutorials the client library has grown over the years its no longer needed.